# Filter rows of strings after a starting row that starts with certain characters

Tags: python, string, rows, startswith

I'm using Python.
I have extracted text from pdf. So I have a data frame full of strings with just one column and no column name.
I need to filter rows from a starting row until the end. This starting row is identified because starts with certain characters. Consider the following example:

```
+----------------+
|   aaaaaaa      |
|   bbbbbb       |
|   ccccccc      |
|   hellodddd    |
|   eeeeeeeee    |
|   fffffffffff  |
|   gggggggg     |
|   hhhhhhhh     |
+----------------+
```

I need to filter rows from the starting row, which is `hellodddd` until the end. As you can see, the starting row is identified because startswith `hello` characters.
So, the expected output is:

```
+----------------+
|   hellodddd    |
|   eeeeeeeee    |
|   fffffffffff  |
|   gggggggg     |
|   hhhhhhhh     |
+----------------+
```

I think this example can be reproduced with the following code:

```
mylist = ['aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbb', 'ccccccc', 'hellodddd', 'eeeeeeeee', 'fffffffffff', 'gggggggg', 'hhhhhhhh']
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

I think I need to use `startswith()` function first to identify the starting row. But, then, what could I do to select the wanted columns (the ones that follow the starting row until the end)?

Comment: Well, do you know how to check each element of the list? Do you know how to keep track of where you are in the list, while doing that? Do you know how to get "everything from here until the end" with a list? If you put those pieces together, does it solve the problem? *Where exactly are you stuck*?

Comment: Yes. I have used pdfminer and I have iterated until I got the elements that I needed (LTChar objects). Then I have arranged then into characters and joined then in rows. What I need now is to isolate the target text I need, and I know that this target text is located before a certain row until the end.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions at all. The question is **not about** PDFs. It *does not matter* how you got your data, if you are asking about what to do with it now.

Answer (score 1):

`.startswith()` is a method on a string, returning whether or not a string starts with some substring, it won't help you select rows in a dataframe (unless you're looking for the first row with a value that starts with that string).

You're looking for something like:

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = ['aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbb', 'ccccccc', 'hellodddd', 'eeeeeeeee', 'fffffffffff', 'hellodddd', 'hhhhhhhh']
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)

print(df[(df[0].values == 'hellodddd').argmax():])
```

Result:

```
             0
3    hellodddd
4    eeeeeeeee
5  fffffffffff
6    hellodddd
7     hhhhhhhh
```

Note that I replaced a later value with `'hellodddd'` as well, to show that it will include all rows from the first match onwards.

Edit: in response to the comment:

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = ['aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbb', 'ccccccc', 'hellodddd', 'eeeeeeeee', 'fffffffffff', 'hellodddd', 'hhhhhhhh']
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)

print(df[(df[0].str.startswith('hello')).argmax():])
```

Result is identical.

Comment: It turns out that my rows come from a text extracted from a pdf, and as you can imagine, are strings, and also very large (as a row in a text would look). So, I first need to identify the starting row and I know that this starting row starts with certain characters (as 'hello' in 'hellodddd'). It should be noted that all rows are strings.

Comment: I've added an update showing how to apply `.startswith()` and select a row to start your selection with that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about panda, but I know that `itertools` can solve this problem:

```py
import itertools

mylist = [
    'aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbb', 'ccccccc', 'hellodddd', 'eeeeeeeee',
    'fffffffffff', 'gggggggg', 'hhhhhhhh'
]

result = list(itertools.dropwhile(
    lambda element: not element.startswith("hello"),
    mylist,
))
```

The `dropwhile` function drop (discard) those element that fits the condition, after that, it returns the rest.

Comment: To make it works for a pandas dataframe: `result = pd.DataFrame(itertools.dropwhile(lambda element: not element.startswith("hello"), df[0].values))`